# Running TestNG tests in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I wanted to run tests defined by TestNG in parallel.

I have @DataProvider method which contains the list of IDs

@BeforeClass method gets every ID, does some processing and stores the result in the Map. There is one @Test method which uses the values present in Map and performs the validation.

I used the following statement within the xml:

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
```

I wanted to run the tests in parallel and the Map computed should not be shared across the thread. The values should be thread specific.

How should I define such a variable and use it only for that thread?

Comment: So, in essence, you have two maps, not one?

Comment: There are thousands of IDs in the data provider. Why two maps ?

Comment: Then your question is unclear or you are doing something wrong. A `@BeforeClass` hook will run when the class is first initialized; therefore if you change the values of this map in your tests, this will lead to an undefined behavior. Please post some sample code.

Comment: Yes. It is actually @BeforeMethod. For every ID obtained from DataProvider, BeforeMethod has to be executed and data has to be computed with which Test will run. This has to run in multiple threads

Comment: Please edit the question with relevant information, then. But most likely what you want here is a `ThreadLocal`